# one of JSON values returns unidentified with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I need to retrieve email field from JSON with JavaScript.
Here is the code:

```
        "contacts": [
            {
                "addedAt": 1332358711001,
                "vid": 1,
                "properties": {
                    "lastname": {
                        "value": "Mott"
                    },
                    "firstname": {
                        "value": "Adrian"
                    }
                },

                "identity-profiles": [
                    {
                        "vid": 1,
                        "identities": [
                            {
                                "type": "EMAIL",
                                "value": "test-fdfc6c2e-e19e-4138-8201-8342ca333aa1@hubspot.com",
                                "timestamp": 1332358711715
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "LEAD_GUID",
                                "value": "f3ebaf07-1c6d-4ada-af31-3559dd8b3027",
                                "timestamp": 1332358711771
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }]
```

The code works with all fields, except when I get to Identities, it returns NULL or unidentified.

```
var temp = fields.contacts.length;
for (var i=0; i<fields.contacts.length; i++){

  var addedAt = fields.contacts[i].addedAt;
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(addedAt), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");

  var lastName = fields.contacts[i].properties.lastname.value;
  var firstName = fields.contacts[i].properties.firstname.value;
  var vid = fields.contacts[i].vid;
  var ip = fields.contacts[i]['identity-profiles'];

  var id = ip.identities;
}
```

var id always returns unidentified. Also doesn't work:

```
for (var j=0; i<id.length; j++){
  if(typeof ['type'] == 'EMAIL'){
    var email = id[j].value;
  }
};
```

Comment: identity-profiles is an array of objects, so you're looking for something like this:
`var id = ip[0].identities;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fields.contacts[i]['identity-profiles']` is an array, it doesn't directly have a `identities` property.

You may want

```
var id = ip[0].identities;
```

or you should iterate over `fields.contacts[i]['identity-profiles']` but it's not clear what you precisely want.

Comment: this worked: email = fields.contacts[i]['identity-profiles'][0].identities[0].value;